# Error while compiling Concurrent YACC program

Tags: c, multithreading, yacc, lex

I am trying to build implement a basic calculator using Concurrent YACC. I have tried the code by statically creating the threads. But whe I want to dynamically specify how many threads to be created, the parser seems to have a problem. Here are the contents of my code.

**aa.y file**

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
void * scanner;
FILE *yyin;
#define YYSTYPE int
%}

%token digit
%lex-param {void * scanner}
%parse-param {void * scanner}
%start list
%token NUMBER
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/' '%'
%left UMINUS 
%union {int i;}
%%

list:                      
    |
    list stat '\n'
    |
    list error '\n'{ yyerrok; }
    ;

stat:   expr { printf("Thread = %d ... Ans = %d\n",pthread_self(),$1);}
    ;

expr:   '(' expr ')'{ $$ = $2; }
    |
    expr '*' expr { $$ = $1 * $3; }
    |
    expr '/' expr { $$ = $1 / $3; }
    |
    expr '+' expr { $$ = $1 + $3; }
    |
    expr '-' expr { $$ = $1 - $3; }
    |
    '-' expr %prec UMINUS { $$ = -$2; }
    |
    NUMBER
    ;

%%

struct struct_arg
{
    unsigned char* file;
};

int yyerror()
{
    return 1;
}

void *parse(void *arguments)
{
    struct struct_arg *args = (struct struct_arg *)arguments;
    unsigned char* filename;
    filename = args -> file;
    yyin = fopen(filename,"r+");
    if(yyin == NULL)
   {

   }
   else
   {
       yylex_init(&scanner);
       yyset_in(yyin,scanner);
       yyparse(scanner);
       yylex_destroy(scanner);
       printf("Thread = %d\n",pthread_self());
   }

   fclose(yyin);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int num;
    printf("How many threads you want to create??\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    int error, count = 0;
    FILE *fp[num], *file_pointer;
    char line[256];
    size_t len = 0;
    char read;

    file_pointer = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file_pointer))
    {
        char file_name[32] = "test_";
        char dummy[4];
        char dummy2[5] = ".txt";
        sprintf(dummy, "%d", count);
        strcat(file_name, dummy);
        strcat(file_name, dummy2);
        fp[count] = fopen(file_name, "a");
        fprintf(fp[count], "%s", line);
        fclose(fp[count]);
        count++;
        if(count == num)
        {
            count = 0;
        }
    }

    struct struct_arg arguments[num];
    int i = 0;
    while(i < num)
    {
        char file_name[32] = "test_";
        char dummy[4];
        char dummy2[5] = ".txt";
        sprintf(dummy, "%d", i);
        strcat(file_name, dummy);
        strcat(file_name, dummy2); 
        arguments[i].file = file_name;
        i++;
    }

    pthread_t tid[num];
    int j = 0;
    while(j < num)
    {
        error = pthread_create(&(tid[j]), NULL, &parse, (void *) &arguments[j]);
        j++;
    }

    int n = 0;
    while(n < num)
    {
        pthread_join(tid[n], NULL);
        n++;
    }

    int temp, k = 0;
    while(k < num)
    {
        char file_name[32] = "test_";
        char dummy[4];
        char dummy2[5] = ".txt";
        sprintf(dummy, "%d", k);
        strcat(file_name, dummy);
        strcat(file_name, dummy2); 
        temp = remove(file_name);
        k++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**aa.l**

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
extern int scanner;
%}
%option reentrant
%option noyywrap
NUMBER      [0-9]+
%%

" "         ;
{NUMBER}    {
                yylval->i = atoi(yytext);
                return(NUMBER);
            }
[^0-9\b]    {
                return(yytext[0]);
            }
```

My compiling steps are

```
yacc -d aa.y
lex aa.l
cc lex.yy.c y.tab.c -o aa.exe -pthread
```

And the error generated is

```
aa.l: In function 'yylex':
aa.l:13:23: error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'YYSTYPE')
            yylval->i = atoi(yytext);
```

Can anyone please point out what I am doing wrong??

Comment: Hello, I am student at University of Pune, and I guess that you're also from the same. I just wanted to know, whether your problem is resolved?

Comment: Yeah, I finally got it running. I had to make a few more minor changes in it.  Check it out here - https://github.com/apoorvasomani/Lex-Yacc-Parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a simple compiler error, which is (indirectly) the result of your not requesting a reentrant ("pure") bison parser. [Note 1]

Since the parser is not reentrant, it uses a global `yylval` which is of type `YYSTYPE`. Your `%union` declaration will create a declaration of `YYSTYPE` as a union type which will be placed in the generated header file `y.tab.h`, which effectively looks something like this (leaving out some unimportant details):

```
#ifndef YYSTYPE
  typedef union yystype {
    int i;
  } YYSTYPE;
  extern YYSTYPE yylval;
#endif
```

That code will also be placed into `y.tab.c`, but it will go *after* the inserted C segment from the `%{...}` section of your bison definition. There you `#define YYSTYPE int`, with the result that in y.tab.c `yylval` has type `int`, whereas in `yy.lex.c, it is a union type. That's undefined behaviour (UB), which is how you say "wrong wrong wrong" in C. (But UB is really undefined; one possibility is that the error is silently ignored.)

Since `yylval` is an instance of `YYSTYPE`, rather than a pointer to a `YYSTYPE`, the correct way of referring to member `i` is `yylval.i`, not `yylval->i`. Hence the compiler error.

In your bison file, you don't declare any of your nonterminals to have a type. Since you're including a `%union` declaration, bison requires you to tell it the type of any terminal or non-terminal whose semantic value is used (with `$1`, `$2`, etc.) or assigned to (with `$$`). So you should have received a pile of errors when you attempted to pass the file through `bison`. On the other hand, if you had declared types, then the bison-generated parser would have contained references to `yylval.i`, and that would also generated compiler errors because your `#define YYSTYPE` effectively bypassed the union declaration. (Bison doesn't know about the `#define` because it doesn't parse included C code. So it can't generate an error message. But it's definitely an error.)

If you had told bison to produce a re-entrant parser, then the generated parser would have called `yylex` with an additional argument of type `YYSTYPE*`; had you also supplied `%option bison-bridge` in the flex definition, then flex would have generated a declaration of `yylex` with an additional parameter of type `YYSTYPE*` which will become the value of `yylval`. In that case, `yylval` will be a pointer, rather than an instance, and `yylval->i` would have been correct.

---

### Notes

1. For some reason, the use of reentrant bison parsers is referred to incorrectly as "Concurrent YACC". That's wrong on two counts: first, the generated parser is not concurrent (although because it is reentrant, it can be used concurrently if the actions don't introduce race conditions), and secondly because the feature is not available in YACC; it's a `bison` extension.

   A quick Google search revealed two uses of the phrase "Concurrent YACC". One of them was in a comment in an [entry in ESR's blog](http://esr.ibiblio.org/?p=6341), describing a tool he wrote some decades ago, before `bison` existed, to make `yacc` parsers reentrant. The other one was a third-year programming assignment in a course on concurrent programming offered by the University of Pune, which uses the phrase "Concurrent YACC" as though it were meaningful.

   I'm guessing that this question derives from the second of those, which might imply that the coursework includes an explanation of what is meant. But for what it's worth, ESR does outline the steps involved in correctly bridging a reentrant bison parser to a reentrant flex lexer. So I suggest you take a look at it, although I do not endorse ESR's description of `%bison-bridge` as buggy. (Had he said "badly-documented kludge", I would have been 100% on-side.)

Comment: I added bison bridge as a reentrant and the error is gone but the program ends with segmentation fault. Is there any good debugger for this?

Comment: Debugging threaded code is not easy. However, gdb is possible. A segfault may well not be a race condition; I'd definitely try verifying that it works single-threaded before launching into the multithreaded version. Good luck.